# PHP zf2 mail return null

Tags: php, email, zend-framework, zend-framework2, send

I try to send an email with ZF2.

I use:

```
    $mail = new Mail\Message();
    $mail->addFrom('email@mail.com', 'name')
    ->addTo('email@mail.com')
    ->setSubject('Cotización')->setBody('This is the text of the mail.');


    try{
    $transport = new Mail\Transport\Sendmail();
    $transport->send($mail);
    }catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        //var_dump($e);
    }
    die();
```

And i get allways "null". In the HTML I get:

```
<pre class="xdebug-var-dump" dir="ltr"><font color="#3465a4">null</font>
```

But I get comment the var_dump and I set die(); but prints me text. I really don't know how I can solve it.
PD: No enter in the exception. I try print text.

Comment: You 'always get null' from what? Your code does not return or echo any value.  Also, ZF2 mail transport does not return a value, so null is what you would expect to get if it works.  Presumably you aren't receiving the email, so 1. do you have sendmail installed? 2. if you use the PHP mail() function instead does that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
//mail
use Zend\Mail\Message;
use Zend\Mail\Transport\Sendmail as SendmailTransport;
use Zend\Mime\Part as MimePart;
use Zend\Mime\Message as MimeMessage;
```

.....

```
function sendEmail($mail){

/*
*Optional; email with style
*
*/
        $this->renderer = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ViewRenderer');
        $content = $this->renderer->render('application/index/mail',array());


        $html = new MimePart($content);
        $html->type = "text/html";

        $body = new MimeMessage();

        $body->setParts(array($html));


        $cabeceras  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $cabeceras .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
 /*
    *Optional; email with style
    *
    */

        $transport = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('mail.transport');
        $message = new Message();
        $message->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine($cabeceras);
        $this->getRequest()->getServer();  //Server vars
        $message->addTo($mail)

            ->addFrom('test@gmail.com')
            ->setSubject('TestSubject')
            ->setEncoding("UTF-8")
            ->setBody($body);

        $transport = new SendmailTransport();
        $transport->send($message);
    }
```